# Bash regular expression not matching inside if

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file `/tmp/gish.dat` which either contains a number (more than 0, and one or more digits) or nothing.

If there is a number present, I want my function to echo a `#` along with the number (eg `#64`). If there is no number present, I want my function to do nothing.

```
   get_issue() {
        if [ -f "/tmp/gish.dat" ]
        then
            iss=$(cat /tmp/gish.dat | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')
            if [[ iss =~ '[0-9]+' ]]
            then
              echo "#$iss"
            fi
        fi
    }
```

For some reason, the inner if never matches. Very new to bash.

Comment: Think you're missing a dollar symbol on your variable. Change it to $iss - in the if condition.

Comment: Assuming your outer if works correctly, try printing the result of the shell call (iss) and check whether this worked correctly. EDIT: Pretty sure you are missing the dollar symbol, as benjamin already mentioned.

Comment: Maybe I also suggest you look at the -s option to test if the file is empty or not :)

Comment: Protip: [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) automatically detects issues like this

Answer (score 4):

If you qoute a regex within `[[...]]` it is only a string.

Replace `'[0-9]+'` by `[0-9]+`.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your code this way:

```
   get_issue() {
        if [ -f "/tmp/gish.dat" ]
        then
            iss=$(grep -Eo '[0-9]+' /tmp/gish.dat)
            if [[ $iss ]]
            then
              echo "#$iss"
            fi
        fi
    }
```

Since `grep -Eo` extracts just the matching numeric part, there is no need to match the extracted string against the regex again in `if`.  `[[ $iss ]]` is true whenever `$iss` is not empty.

Comment: Thanks that is great.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to print something like #64, #45 etc then change your code as follows,

```
 if [ -f "/tmp/gish.dat" ]
    then
        iss=$(cat /tmp/gish.dat | grep -Eo '[0-9]+' | tr '\n' ' ')
        for isss in $iss    
        do  
                if [[ $isss =~ '[0-9]+' ]]
                then
                  echo "#$isss"
                fi  
        done;
```

fi

check out this one